# How to disable Android night mode for notifications?

Tags: android

My app has got a foreground service that sends notifications with RemoteViews. When a user selects Android's night mode, he can't read the notification anymore because it's black text on black background.

Is there a way to disable the night mode for my app's notifications?

I've tried to use `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` in the notification service class onCreate but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make a night mode layout instead with white font color.